# Unable to upvote

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

With Version 0.1.4 I am unable to upvote Questions or Answers and I get the error the user has not earned the privilege needed for vote of Question(Answer) via the API.

Now that I have the privilege of downvoting on the site I attempted to downvote on the app and got the same message. Also I tried to upvote/downvote this question on the app and instead of getting the message saying I can't vote on my own question I got the have not earned the privilege message.

Comment: Are you able to downvote though? That's the most important thing.... ;)

Comment: @Bart I need 4 more rep before I earn the privilege of downvoting and the ability to test that :)

Comment: I am assuming that whoever upvoted this confirmed the issue via the app. But then... how did they upvote?

Comment: @Oded: So the lack of upvotes on this post can be seen as proof of the bugs validity then? :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters - You are treading over the metaphysical line here. My head hurts.

Comment: Over the metastackoverflow line, in any event.

Comment: What is version 0.1.4?

Comment: @kiamlaluno The version of the Stack Exchange Android app which I am currently using in the alpha test.

Comment: I just upvoted this using the Android app and now I can't tell if I should make a meta-meta joke or just stay confused.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi I just tested voting on Stack Overflow where I have more rep and I was able to upvote there but on Meta Stack Overflow I get this error when attempting to upvote, downvote or remove a vote.

Comment: This seems to be fixed as I can vote properly now in version 0.1.6 and get the proper error message when trying to vote on my own posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, this was fixed a very long time ago.