# Unable to take actions on Questions/Answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

On version 0.1.4, I am unable to take any actions that I am able to take on questions/answers that I would normally able to on the website such as share/edit/flag/delete (my own posts).

Comment: You couldn't edit this into http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192459/unable-to-upvote ?

Comment: I can but I believe this is a different issue then being unable to upvote or downvote a question.

Comment: Sharing a question is under the menu when you tap on the time stamp. It uses the native Android sharer. Doesn't look like you can share answers right now. I can't find the source, but I think they said other actions like flagging, editing, etc are coming soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed when we added more options to that dialog. There is now at least one action you can take no matter if you're anonymous, logged in but don't belong to a community, or are looking at your own post.