# Cannot upvote answers when accessed from the Android app feed

Tags: bug, android-app, up-votes

I was having a problem upvoting an answer to my question on CodeReview.SE *when accessed from the feed* via Android app. My repetitive tapping on the arrow did nothing, so I had to do it the old way (on web-site).

Note that I was able to upvote/un-upvote via app when I selected a post from a site view.

Comment: Yay for voting on CR!

Comment: This is a bug, according to [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192459/unable-to-upvote#comment600917_192459) it should be possible to upvote via the app.

Comment: This should be working. Are you getting an error (bright red message at the top of the screen)? Are you on a mobile internet connection?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi - I was on WiFi connection.  After I already upvoted on the site I tried again to upvote on my cell, then after several taps I got a red message that I already voted on this answer 6 minutes ago.

Comment: I couldn't repro this on v1.0.82 (beta) {I know it has been long since then}. Probably it has been fixed, though there is another issue related to voting (unrelated to this particular issue)